# Three Different Numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm

I`m stuck on the problem below. My solution exceeds the time limit. Can someone give me an idea how to improve it?

You just need to count the number of ordered triples of different numbers (X1, X2, X3), where Xi could be any positive integer from 1 to Ni, inclusive (i = 1, 2, 3).
Numbers N1, N2, N3 could be up to 10^18.
Because of this the answer could be quite large. Hence you should output it modulo 10^9 + 7.

Input

The first line of the input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows. The only line of each test case contains three space-separated integers N1, N2, N3.

Output

For each test case, output a single line containing the number of required triples modulo 10^9 + 7.

Constraints

1 ≤ T ≤ 1000

1 ≤ Ni ≤ 10^18

```
Example

Input:

5

3 3 3
2 4 2
1 2 3
25 12 2012
1 1 2013

Output:
6
4
1
578880
0
```

Here is my solution:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int t;
scanf("%d",&t);
for(int i=0; i<t; i++)
{
    long long unsigned a,b,c,sum=0,s1,s2,s3;
    scanf("%llu %llu %llu", &a,&b,&c);
    for(s1=1; s1<=a; s1++)
    {
        for(s2=1; s2<=b; s2++)
        {
            if(s1==s2) continue;
            for(s3=1; s3<=c; s3++)
            {
                if(s1==s3 || s2==s3) continue;
                sum=(sum+1)%1000000007;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%llu\n",sum);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: this smells like a homework question. why are you looking to have this improved?

Comment: Yes, it is homework. I can`t pass the 2 sec time limit with this solution.

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking your professor or TA for help rather than cheating on your homework?

Comment: How is this cheating, this homework is for practice and doesn't give me anything. Besides I've tried myself and I don't expect someone to give me a complete solution just point me in the right direction.

Comment: The 2 seconds limit with numbers up to 10^18 is a **huge** hint that you must find a constant time solution. Stop thinking it is a programming problem, and start approaching it like a math problem maybe this will help.

Comment: @SGM1 "of different numbers".

Comment: It's cheating because you are trying to get homework credit for work that you didn't do. That typically goes by names like *academic dishonesty* or *plagiarism*.

Comment: Well I've solved it myself as you can see. Plagiarism would be if someone gave me the solution and I've used it as mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've found out that you can calculate the number of ordered triples easy so here is the solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
const long long unsigned the_prime= 1000000007;
int t;
scanf("%d",&t);
for(int i=0; i<t; i++)
{
    long long unsigned m[3],res=0;
    scanf("%llu %llu %llu", &m[0],&m[1],&m[2]);
    sort(m,m+3);
    res=((((m[0]%the_prime)*((m[1]-1)%the_prime))%the_prime)*((m[2]-2)%the_prime))%the_prime;
    printf("%llu\n",res);
}
return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Ya its a counting problem, n1 * (n2-1) * (n3-1), but this is only true when n1 < n2 < n3